# Inserting data into multiple different data tables

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to insert data into multiple data tables. It's only working for single data tables, I'm just wondering how I would be able to insert data into two data tables. I've been struggling with this issue for the past few hours and can't seem to get to the bottom of it. If anyone has any advice please let me know. :)

```
    <?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","ivodatat","","");


if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Inputs for security 
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['fname']);
$sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sname']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$mac = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['mac']);
$installer = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['installer']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['status']);

// Insert Query 
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO leadlist (fname, sname, address, email, phone, mac, installer, status) VALUES ('$fname', '$sname', '$address', '$email', '$phone', '$mac', '$installer', '$status')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO $installer (fname, sname, address, email, phone, mac, installer, status) VALUES ('$fname', '$sname', '$address', '$email', '$phone', '$mac', '$installer', '$status')";



if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql1, $sql2)){



                mysqli_close($conn);
                header("Location: installercontrol.php");




                exit;

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close The Connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Michael Cunningham, is there a SQL exception?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Run each query individually. Check for any errors that result. Don't just smash-execute both. It also looks like you have potentially multiple tables with an identical schema, one per installer. This is contrary to proper relational database design and massively complicates queries. Instead have an `installer_id` type column to relate the data. Additionally, column names use a different escaping mechanism than string values and `mysqli_real_escape_string` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

To use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you need to append the queries to each other as it only takes one query argument. From the manual:

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Try this instead:

```
mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql1 . ';' . $sql2)
```

You should probably also update your error message:

```
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql1;$sql2. " . mysqli_error($link);
```

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query` is extremely hazardous to use because it does not support placeholder values. It can almost always be avoided.

Comment: @tadman absolutely, but OPs question was why it wasn't working. I think you've covered the issues pretty well in your comments.