# Updating SQL Data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my second topic tonight, but it's only because I can't really find any helpful information in regards to updating data in SQL using php. For some reason this won't update. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great :), again sorry for asking another question, I'm just eager to learn from my mistakes.

HTML Section:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Update Data</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="editphpscript.php" method="post">

            ID To Update: <input type="text" name="id" required><br><br>

            New Status: <select name="status" required>
                <option>Status</option>
                <option value="Assigned">Assigned</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="No_Signal">No Signal</option>
                <option value="Installed">Installed</option>
            </select>



            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Data">

        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

PHP Section

```
<?php
// php code to Update data from mysql database Table

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

   $hostname = "";
   $username = "";
   $password = "";
   $databaseName = "";

   $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

   // get values form input text and number

   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $status = $_POST['status'];

   // mysql query to Update data
   $query = "UPDATE `leadlist` SET `status`='".$status." WHERE `id` = $id";

   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query){

   ($result){
       echo 'Data Updated';
   }else{
       echo 'Data Not Updated';
   }
   mysqli_close($connect);
}

?>
```

Comment: Look like you miss some quotes in your SQL command: `"UPDATE leadlist SET status='$status' WHERE id = '$id'"`

Comment: you are open to sql injection attacks, don't use this code in production

Comment: Do you have any suggestions then on how to update data then?

Comment: looking at your last question, you were advised how to do it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting data into multiple different data tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700872/inserting-data-into-multiple-different-data-tables)

Comment: you can try to show the error of your query using mysqli_error($connect )

Comment: $query = "UPDATE `leadlist` SET `status`= ' ".$status." ' WHERE `id` = ". $id;